# Why add "Eq" type constraint without using "=="?

Tags: haskell

So, I have a very simple function that take two parameters : the first is a hour (between 0 and 23) and the second one is a minute (between 0 and 59). This function return the hour plus one minute, and format the hour in a beautiful style. By example, `hour 11 12` return `11 heures et 13 minutes`. Sorry for the french format of the hour.

So, I use in this function the `show` function, and the parameters need to be a number, so I have the type declaration `(Num a, Show a) => a -> a -> String`. But, when I try the function, I got an error and GHC say to me to add the `Eq` type constraint, but I don't understand why I need the `Eq` type constraint in this case. There is the code (again, sorry for the french text used in the function, but I think that it's not very important if you don't understand the function name and the text) :

```
heure :: (Num a, Eq a, Show a) => a -> a -> String
heure 23 59 = "Minuit"
heure 12 m  = "Midi et " ++ show (m+1) ++ " minutes"
heure h 59  = show (h+1) ++ " heures"
heure h m   = show h ++ " heures et " ++ show (m+1) ++ " minutes"
```

So : if I don't use `Eq`, I have an error and when I use it my code is correct. Why?

Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: Matching a numeric, character, or string literal pattern k against a value v succeeds if v  ==  k, where == is overloaded based on the type of the pattern. See [Haskell 2010 Language Report 3.17.2 Informal Semantics of Pattern Matching](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17)

Comment: @nymk: [Section 6.4 of the 2010 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1350006.4) says "[t]he class `Num` of numeric types is a subclass of `Eq`, since all numbers may be compared for equality." But what's going on here is that [recent versions of GHC don't do it](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/release-7-4-1.html): "The `Num` class no longer has `Eq` or `Show` superclasses. A number of other classes and functions have therefore gained explicit `Eq` or `Show` constraints, rather than relying on a `Num` constraint to provide them."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the `Eq` constraint because you're checking whether `h` is equal to `23` or `12` and whether `m` is equal to `59`. You're doing it using pattern matching, not `==`, but pattern matching against numeric literals that way still requires `Eq` (unlike pattern matching against constructors).