# Why does a function constructed with pattern matching have the Eq type constraint but not when using a data constructor?

Tags: haskell, equality, typeclass, ghci, algebraic-data-types

Why does ghci list an [equality type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Eq.html) constraint in the type signature for this function `matchInt` which I constructed via pattern matching:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :{
Prelude| matchInt 1 = 3
Prelude| matchInt _ = 4
Prelude| :}
Prelude> matchInt 1
3
Prelude> matchInt 22
4
Prelude> :t matchInt
matchInt :: (Eq a, Num a, Num p) => a -> p
```

In contrast, when using a simple data constructor, there is no equality type constraint.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.2.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> data Z = Y Int
Prelude> :{
Prelude| matchDataInt (Y 1) = 3
Prelude| matchDataInt _ = 4
Prelude| :}
Prelude> matchDataInt (Y 1)
3
Prelude> matchDataInt (Y 22)
4
Prelude> :t matchDataInt
matchDataInt :: Num p => Z -> p
```

Indeed instances of Z can **not** be compared:

```
Prelude> Y 22 == Y 33
<interactive>:11:1: error:
    • No instance for (Eq Z) arising from a use of ‘==’
    • In the expression: Y 22 == Y 33
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = Y 22 == Y 33
```

So again, why does the `matchInt` function list equality as a type constraint but not the function `matchDataInt`?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512541/why-add-eq-type-constraint-without-using) is related. However, if an equality test is needed for `matchInt` then why isn't it needed for `matchDataInt`? And here I come to my key point: don't **both** `matchInt` and `matchDataInt` have to test against 1 for the pattern matching to operate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Syntactically `matchInt` is built on a pattern match, but the patern match here is an illusion. `1` is not a data constructor. Numeric literals are overloaded. `1` is equivalent to `fromInteger #1` where `#1` is a non-overloaded litteral (not expressible in standard Haskell) of type `Integer`. You cannot really pattern match against such things.

So the compiler lets you write what is syntactically a pattern match, but this notation really denotes a guard:

```
matchInt 1 = ... -- what is written
matchInt x | x == fromInteger #1 = ...  -- what it really means
```

Since the type of `matchInt` is not explicitly given, it's inferred. It's a function, so the type is some refinement of `a->b`. The call to `fromInteger` gives rise to the constraint `Num a`, and the call to `==` gives rise to the constraint `Eq a`, and that's all we can tell about `a`.

If OTOH we give the function an explicit signature, say

```
matchInt :: Int->Int
```

then we don't need to infer the type, but only check if it satisfies the constraints. Since `Int` satisfies both `Eq Int` and `Num Int`, everything is ok.

And this is what's going on in your second example. The type you match is known to be `Int`, not because of an explicit type signature but because it is inferred from the `Y Int` alternative of `Z`. Here again `Int` already has all the needed instances.

Answer (score 7):

The `matchDataInt` function doesn't require an `Eq` constraint because it *specifically matches on an `Int`*, and `Int`s already have an `Eq` instance.

Your `matchInt` function doesn't just take `Int`s as parameters – it can take *any* kind of number, as long as you can compare that number for equality.  That's why it has type `(Eq a, Num a, Num p) => a -> p`.  You could also give it the type `Num p => Int -> p` (specializing `a` to `Int`), because `Int` already has `Eq` and `Num` instances.

Your `matchDataInt` function, on the other hand, takes a `Z` as an argument, and every `Z` contains an `Int`.  Pattern matching against *that `Int`* incurs an `Eq` constraint, but *only on the `Int`*.  You could instead have

```
data Z' a = Y' a

matchDataNum :: (Eq a, Num a, Num p) => Z' a -> p
matchDataNum (Y' 1) = 3
matchDataNum _      = 4
```

And here, you couldn't remove the `Eq a` constraint.

---

This all might be slightly clearer with variant functions that didn't return numbers themselves.  If we have

```
data Z    = Y  Int
data Z' a = Y' a

is1 1 = True
is1 _ = False

isY1 (Y 1) = True
isY1 _     = False

isY'1 (Y' 1) = True
isY'1 _      = False
```

then the three functions we've defined have the types

```
is1   :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> Bool
isY1  :: Z -> Bool
isY'1 :: (Eq a, Num a) => Z' a -> Bool
```

We could also define

```
is1Int :: Int -> Bool
is1Int 1 = True
is1Int _ = False
```